# Android 6.0 permission dialog not showing

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

I want to try request permission in Android 6.0, but I have a trouble.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.zhangkaiyue.jkdemo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Activity

```
    mLv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                int checkPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(UsingCustomLayoutActivity.this, Manifest.permission_group.LOCATION);
                if (checkPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UsingCustomLayoutActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission_group.LOCATION}, 111);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(UsingCustomLayoutActivity.this, "haha", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 111){
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(UsingCustomLayoutActivity.this, "hehe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(UsingCustomLayoutActivity.this, "heihei", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

When I click one item, permission dialog not showing, and toast text is `heihei`, I don't know why, please help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot request permission for a whole permission group, as you do with `Manifest.permission_group.LOCATION`.

You have to request the specific permission, i.e. `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`.

```
int checkPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(UsingCustomLayoutActivity.this, 
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

if (checkPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UsingCustomLayoutActivity.this, 
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 111);
}
```

Also note that the permission `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` is implicitly granted if you already have `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, so you may just omit it.

Answer (score 1):

Please double-check if your `<uses-permission/>`-Tags are **really outside** of your `<application />` Tag. Even tough I read the same hint several times, it took me about 2 hours to realize I did the same mistake...